# uiSettings funciona el zoom control pero no el MyLocationButtonEnable ¿Por que pasa esto?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, kotlin

Estoy usando androidStudio kotlin y el boton de zoom de google  [+ -] aparece en la parte inferior del mapa pero la diana de google no aparece. Tampoco aparece la brújula.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener( this )

        setMapStyle ()
        setUpMap()

        //Desplegar ubicacion propia
        this.mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        this.mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        this.mMap.uiSettings.isCompassEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El include tiene que estar con la propiedad constraintTop por debajo del toolbar:

```
<include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" /> <!--here-->
```

[image: Finalmente la brújula y el botón (MyLocationButtonEnabled) no se veían porque el contenedor del google maps estaba siendo tapado por el toolbar celeste.]